# What is the partition message routing algorithm in azure service bus

Tags: azureservicebus

I want to ensure that my messages are evenly distributed across partitions in service bus. We currently have messages that are being sent with a sessionId set to id.ToString() where Id is an integer. However, I am wondering, if this would be sufficient to distribute messages well enough. As far as I can tell, there's no way to confirm how sessions are being distributed, so have no way to test this.

I can see in this sample that session Ids are being prefixed with "session" https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/BasicSessionSendReceiveUsingQueueClient

Is this something coincidental to my question? Or is this something I should do If my sessionId will be derived from an integer? The concern here is if service bus uses a ranged partitioning scheme such as that of service fabric, then integer values that are close to each other will be placed on the same partition.

EDIT: to be specific, this question is about ensuring messages are distributed evenly across the partitions inside service bus (not load balancing competiting consumers of sessions) - i've updated the question to better reflect this.

Thanks,

Comment: The prefix used in the sample could be any value other than "session". Session ID is used to identify a session. In terms of distributing the load, number of max concurrent sessions times number of processing nodes is what will take the sessions. The rest is competing consumers I'd guess.

Comment: Thanks @SeanFeldman - my question is pertaining specifically to the distribution of messages across partitions in service bus.. not distribution of sessions across consumers. I think this can be applied more generally to usage of PartitionKey.

Answer (score 1):

As [What are partitioned queues and topics?](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/partitioned-service-bus-queues-and-topics/) explained as follows:

> In a nutshell, a partitioned queue or topic works as follows: **Each partitioned queue or topic consists of multiple fragments**. Each fragment is stored in a different messaging store and handled by a different message broker. **When a message is sent to a partitioned queue or topic, Service Bus assigns the message to one of the fragments. The selection is done randomly by Service Bus or by a partition key that can be specified by the sender**.

> When a message is enqueued into a partitioned queue or topic, Service Bus **checks for the presence of a partition key**. If it finds one it selects the fragment based on that key. **If it doesn’t, it selects the fragment based on an internal algorithm**. **Using a partition key** Some scenarios, such as **sessions** or **transactions**, require messages to be stored in a certain fragment. All of these scenarios require the use of a partition key. All messages that use the same partition key are assigned to the same fragment. Depending on the scenario, different message properties are used as a partition key.

For the sessions scenario, it states as follows:

> If a message has the **SessionId** property set, then Service Bus **uses the SessionId property as the partition key**. This way, **all messages that belong to the same session are assigned to the same fragment and handled by the same message broker**. This allows Service Bus to guarantee message ordering as well as the consistency of session states.

Moreover, if you do not specify message properties (`SessionId` or `PartitionKey` or `MessageId`) which would be used as a partition key, then Service Bus distributes messages **in a round robin manner** to all the fragments of the partitioned queue or topic. If the chosen fragment is not available, Service Bus assigns the message to a different fragment.

For more details, you could refer to [Partitioned Service Bus Queues and Topics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/partitioned-service-bus-queues-and-topics/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment bruce. I have poured over that article many times. What it is missing is the explanation of how it "selects the fragment based on that key. " For instance, it could use a modulo operation . Or it could use a ranged partition... I'm sure there are many... but what does AzureServiceBus use?

Comment: I have checked that the algorithm about selecting the fragment based on that key is not documented. If you want to know how did azure service bus implement it, you could add your comment under [Partitioned queues and topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning) or add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216926-service-bus).

Comment: Feedback better to provide at [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues), under `documentation` label.